# Is there a way to touch-enable scrolling in a WPF ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, touch

I'm trying to create a form in a WPF application that will allow the user to use iPhone-like gestures to scroll through the available fields. So, I've put all my form controls inside a StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer, and the scrollbar shows up as expected when there are too many elements to be shown on the screen.

However, when I try to test this on my touch-enabled device, a panning gesture (placing a finger down on the surface and dragging it upward) does not move the viewable area down as I would expect.

When I simply put a number of elements inside a ListView, the touch gestures work just fine. Is there any way to enable the same kind of behavior in a ScrollViewer?

My window is structured like this:

```
 <Window x:Class="TestTouchScrolling.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>        
    <ScrollViewer Name="viewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Name="panel">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label>Label 1:</Label>
                <TextBox Name="TextBox1"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label>Label 2:</Label>
                <TextBox Name="TextBox2"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label>Label 3:</Label>
                <TextBox Name="TextBox3"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <!-- Lots more like these -->

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 78):

You should use the attached properties:

- ScrollViewer.PanningMode
- ScrollViewer.PanningDeceleration
- ScrollViewer.PanningRatio

The PanningMode defaults to None in the ScrollViewer default style, but setting it to another value will enable touch scrolling.  I'm currently investigating using this feature in my app and am looking for a good deceleration and ratio value... I'll probably just have to test them out to find something that works well.

Comment: Mind that these properties are under `Miscellaneous` tab AND they **are not available in Silverlight**, just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using .NET 4.0, there is a cool thing recently released by Microsoft team!! They ported all those nice Surface controls to Win7. SurfaceScrollViewer is really cool like iphone one. Install this toolkit and start a SurfaceWin7Touch project from VS2010 project template
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716

Comment: Hello Jobi,The above link is not working , could you please post a working link. Thank you!!!

Comment: The link is broken