# How to scroll ListBoxes naturally on the touch-screens in WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, touchscreen

I am developing WPF application which will be executing on the 21-inch touch-screen.

Along with ListBoxes in my application I have vertical scroll-bars for each of them. What I want is to get rid of those scroll-bars and just allow user to scroll naturally by touching lists itself. How can I achieve that? Is there out-of-the-box support for that in Windows 7 and .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/wpf/thread/8cb1e3f1-43ec-4802-a69d-bcba7d1519ff)

Although WPF supports touch events [out of the box WPF is very limited for this kind of scenario.](http://www.ningzhang.org/2010/10/08/touch-support-in-wpf/)

I am hoping for 3rd parties (or even Microsoft) to add the Windows 8/Metro touch experience to WPF

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but it came up for me first in Google.  So just in case someone else comes here, the answer to this is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829697/is-there-a-way-to-touch-enable-scrolling-in-a-wpf-scrollviewer) SO question.  Simply set the PanningMode, PanningDeceleration, and PanningRatio for the ScrollViewer.

It worked for me on a ComboBox as well.

```
<ComboBox ... ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalOnly" />
```