# How to allow both stylus/pen and fingers touch for scrolling WPF Scrollviewer

Tags: wpf, touch, scrollview, stylus-pen

We developed a WPF application that can be opened in tablets. However the scroll viewer cannot be scrolled using pen/stylus, but can be scrolled using finger touch. How to support both?

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerA" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PanningMode="VerticalOnly" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="ScrollViewerA_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback"><!--Contents Here--></ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829697/is-there-a-way-to-touch-enable-scrolling-in-a-wpf-scrollviewer